# Google Sheets API - PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to access some data from a Google Sheet using the V4 Spreadsheets API and am getting a 403 with PERMISSION_DENIED.  I have verified that the API has been enabled and am passing key={MY_KEY} in the URL. I set the sharing settings to "Anyone with a link" in my personal Google account which is working fine and I am getting data back using the following URL:

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/**MY_KEY**/values/Sheet1?key=**MY_KEY**

However, at work we use GSuite and Link Sharing is restricted to our organization only so when I hit that URL for a Sheet in my work account with the same setup from my personal account (excluding the sharing settings), I get the 403 with PERMISSION_DENIED.

I don't see any documentation as to how to authorize outside of an organization or if its possible to add an exemption to be able to share outside of the organization.

Comment: Have you tried Sharing the sheet file to your email (with read, write or edit permissions)and then actually doing operations on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have an exemption from the sharing settings. If the policy prohibits sharing outside the organization, then the credentials accessing the sheet must be from a user in the organization.

Comment: I have the same situation and am struggling with how to set this up. The service account is automatically set up with an email address that ends in `iam.gserviceaccount.com`. How do I change that so the credentials are in the organization?

I'm not an admin of our GSuite account so it might be possible that I am lacking privs to update that field, but I don't see any documentation on how to do it.